# Get possible hyphenation for the selected word

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript, hyphenation

I am new to scripting in Adobe Software.

I would like to write a script, which shows me, where I can hyphenate a word. I wonder, if there is any way to get this information from the build in spellchecker. It should also take the current language into consideration.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
// Get the current selection
var mySelection = app.selection;

// Check, if it is a word
if (mySelection instanceof Word) {
    // Get the possible hypenation options
    var hyphenated = 

    // Add all hyphenation options to the text string
    mySelection[0].contents = hyphenated;
 }
```

I know it is not much, but I can’t find any way to access the spellchecker manually.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get hyphenation info via scripting.

I suppose the best you could do would be to create a text frame, insert the word, than make the frame increasingly narrow and see where InDesign hyphenates. But that is a pretty klydgy workaround!